# How do you get a list of all project iterations using the Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I'd like to get a list of all the iterations for a given project in a Azure DevOps repository, using the .NET API.

Is there any example of how to do this?  The current documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi.workhttpclientbase.getteamiterationsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) is pretty thin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a working example of how to achieve this.

You need to reference `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Work.WebApi`.

```
public async Task<List<TeamSettingsIteration>> GetProjectIterations(string serverUrl, string projectName)
{
    var uri = new Uri(serverUrl);
    var creds = new VssClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(true), new VssFederatedCredential(true), CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);

    var azureDevopsConnection = new VssConnection(uri, creds);
    await azureDevopsConnection.ConnectAsync();

    WorkHttpClient azureDevOpsWorkHttpClient = azureDevopsConnection.GetClient<WorkHttpClient>();
    TeamContext teamContext = new TeamContext(projectName);

    List<TeamSettingsIteration> results=  await azureDevOpsWorkHttpClient.GetTeamIterationsAsync(teamContext);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Thanks for this example. This code lists the iterations on the teamcontext. How do I get the entire Project iteration list?